# CORBA: Adding objects in Naming Context dynamically

Tags: java, corba

I am building one application in CORBA

I wanted to have object repository on server and let client create and access it .
I will be fully implement it in Java

i have a two solution

1. In here i want to dynamically create a object and add references in Naming context 
   and have a access to this object references to client by providing a Naming Context to object
2. have a central Map to store references to created the object in it

With Solution one , drawback identified : client will have a connect to new naming context

Which one will be better ?
or any other solution exist ?

Comment: The COS Naming service is already written. Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: So using COS Naming service , i can implement above functionality , right.

Comment: but having too much of object references like 500-600 on Naming service will that affect anyting on naming service ?
is there limit on number of objects that i can bind to naming service ?

Comment: Stop worrying. The COS Naming service is designed to do this. You won't do better by trying to invent your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the COS naming service for the standard approach, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279987/access-java-corba-nameservice). CORBA object reference is very light, same as URL. The naming service just keeps the name-to-IOR map and does not maintain persistent connections with all registered objects. Hence you can bind to it more objects that you probably would ever need unless doing something very unusual.